# Method overriding in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I've defined a base class Message which has several derived classes that represent specific message types. Every message type has an associated serialization and deserialization function. The base class has a field 'type' while the subclasses contain message specific fields.

```
class Message
{
public:

    int seq;
    Message();
    ~Message();

    char getType();
    void setType(char);
    virtual void deserializeMsg(const char [256], Message&);
    virtual void serializeMsg(Message&, std :: vector<char>);

private:
    char type;
};

class DataMsg : public Message
{
public:
    string data;
    DataMsg();
    ~DataMsg();
    void serializeMsg(DataMsg&, std :: vector<char>);
    void deserializeMsg(const char [256], DataMsg&);
};
```

The methods look like this :

```
void DataMsg :: serializeMsg(DataMsg &m, std :: vector<char> out)
{
    char type = m.getType();
    char temp [256];
    uint16_t seq = htons(m.seq);
    memcpy(temp, &type, sizeof(type));
    memcpy(temp + sizeof(type), &seq, sizeof(seq));
    memcpy(temp + sizeof(seq) + sizeof(type), m.data.c_str(), m.data.length());
    out.assign(temp, temp + sizeof(seq) + sizeof(type) + m.data.length());
}

void DataMsg :: deserializeMsg(const char out[256], DataMsg& m)
{
    char type = m.getType();
    memcpy(&type, out, sizeof(type));
    out += sizeof(type);
    uint16_t seq;
    memcpy(&seq, out, sizeof(seq));
    m.seq = ntohs(seq);

}
```

I'm declaring a pointer to a Message in the main, and assigning it to one of the subclasses depending on the type field of the received message.

```
int main()
{
    char* buf;
    buf = "D0001";
    Message* a;
    if(buf[0] == 'D')
    {
        a = new DataMsg;
        a -> deserializeMsg(buf, *a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am, however, unable to figure out how to override the serializeMsg and deserializeMsg methods. Using virtual doesn't work because the signatures of the methods are different. If I make identical signatures, I can't access the subclass fields through the base class reference.
Can I access subclass members through a base class reference? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you pass `DataMsg &m`? your methods should work on the instance.

Comment: why you have different signatures ? Could you explain why this is required ?

Comment: I need to assign values to the message fields in the deserialization function, and every message has some unique fields. If I use a common signature, I can't access those fields. @KarolyHorvath You mean I should pass by value?

Comment: Signatures must be the same and you should go for the virtual function solution, if you want to pass different messages , you can always cast DataMsg to a different class into the implementation, that's why you should use pointers instead of references... By the way, if you provide a sample of two different implementations/classes we can further discuss this...

Comment: Just added the class definitions. I was trying to use virtual functions, but it wasn't working because of the different signatures.

Comment: Make sure that you read @KarolyHorvath's initial comment, and understand what he's sayig. It looks like you're missing some fundamentals of C++ and object oriented programming. You're passing a DataMsg instance to your methods, and operating on it. One basic concept of OOP is that you invoke methods on instances of a class, and the methods operate on **that instance**. In this case, your methods should not have a DataMsg argument, but work on the instance they have been invoked on. This also solves your problem of needing different signatures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the second argument in `deserializeMsg`.

Change the signature in the base class to:

```
virtual void deserializeMsg(const char [256]);
```

Change the implementation in `DataMsg` to just use `this` instead of the second argument.

```
void DataMsg :: deserializeMsg(const char out[256])
{
    char type = this->getType(); // Not sure why you need this.
                                 // You are overriding its value in the next line.
    memcpy(&type, out, sizeof(type));
    out += sizeof(type);
    uint16_t seq;
    memcpy(&seq, out, sizeof(seq));
    this->seq = ntohs(seq);    
}
```

You can similar changes to the signature of `serializeMsg` and its implementation in `DataMsg`.

```
virtual void serializeMsg(std :: vector<char>& out);
// Without using `std::vector<char>&`, any changes you make in 
// the function to out are only local changes. The changes won't
// be visible to the calling function.


void DataMsg :: serializeMsg(std :: vector<char>& out)
{
    char type = this->getType();
    char temp [256];
    uint16_t seq = htons(this->seq);
    memcpy(temp, &type, sizeof(type));
    memcpy(temp + sizeof(type), &seq, sizeof(seq));
    memcpy(temp + sizeof(seq) + sizeof(type), this->data.c_str(), this->data.length());
    out.assign(temp, temp + sizeof(seq) + sizeof(type) + this->data.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok , you should go with this:

```
virtual void deserializeMsg(const char [256], Message*);
virtual void serializeMsg(Message*, std :: vector<char>);
```

then in the derived class:

```
void DataMsg :: serializeMsg(Message *m, std :: vector<char> out)
{
    DataMsg* msg = (DataMsg*)m;
}
```

As I said you before, if you go with pointers, you can cast base class pointers to derived class ones, use the same signatures but pass the data you like...

Comment: and by the way, you should make deserializeMSg and serializeMsg static functions , or it has no sense to pass again a pointer/object..